# How exactly does binding work for list of ViewModels in ReactiveUI

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datatemplate, reactiveui

I am currently learning ReactiveUI for WPF. I have rebuilt the following example project and tried to understand it: https://www.reactiveui.net/docs/getting-started/compelling-example

I could understand everything so far, except for one thing. In the example, a list of ViewModels (NugetDetailsViewModel) is connected to a ListBox in a view. I would like to understand what happens in the binding in the background, so that in the end the actual view (NugetDetailsView) is loaded and displayed in the application correctly.

In the documentation in the View Location section (https://www.reactiveui.net/docs/handbook/view-location/) it only says the following:

```
// Now ListBox automatically gets a DataTemplate
this.OneWayBind(ViewModel, vm => vm.ToasterList, v => v.ToasterList.ItemsSource);
```

Unfortunately, the information doesn't help. Maybe you can help me further.
Thank you!

Comment: The easiest way to use View Location is via the ViewModelViewHost control, which is a View (on Cocoa, a UIView/NSView, and on XAML-based platforms a Control) which has a single ViewModel property. When the ViewModel property is set, View Location looks up the associated View and loads it into the container

Comment: https://pasoft-sharereactiveui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/basics/view-location/